# SHA1 encoding with secret, equivalent to PHP hash_hmac

Tags: go, sha1

I have the following PHP function

```
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
        return hash_hmac('sha1', $raw . $salt, $this->secret);
    }
```

which I need to translate to Go. I found the following example, but it doesn't involve secret key.
https://gobyexample.com/sha1-hashes

How can I create a function in Go, that produces exactly same result as PHP's hash_hmac?

> Update: After Leo's answer, found this resource with hmac examples in
>   many languages: https://github.com/danharper/hmac-examples. Can be
>   useful to somebody.

Comment: Did you already try the [hmac package](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/hmac/)?

Comment: For sha1 encoding: `hmac.New(sha1.New, key)`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
import "crypto/sha1"
import "crypto/hmac"

func hash_hmac_sha1(password, salt, key []byte) []byte {
    h := hmac.New(sha1.New, key)
    h.Write(password)
    h.Write(salt)
    return h.Sum(nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Like this function:

```
func decriptSign(message string, key string) string {
    h := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(key))
    h.Write([]byte(message))        
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}
```